# Throttling Netty connections

Tags: connection, netty, throttling

I'm trying to find a replacement for our inhouse Non-Blocking reactor and so far Netty seems like a good fit. The only thing I couldn't figure out is if there is any throttling support for connections. I'd like to control both the incoming as well as the outgoing rate for individual connections. Is there any support or would I have to write my own throttler on top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at:

[io.netty.handler.traffic](http://grepcode.com/search?query=io.netty.handler.traffic&n=)

Comment: That looks promising, particularly because it allows for really granular throttling. Is this going to be part of the 4.0.0 release?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't something like that in netty. But contributions are always welcome ;)